# How do I expose display routes from a specific view as REST API?

Tags: views, 9

I have set up some displays in a *Categories* view, all with their own path. I want to expose all displays from that view with a REST API.

I've already set up a module with a path, but how do I get the paths to the individual displays?

`$view = Views::getView('categories');` gives me the view (probably with my desired displays), but I am quite stuck there.

Most of the answers I find online are pretty much outdated.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found a solution which is working for me myself.

```
$view = Views::getView('categories');

$displays = $view->storage->get('display');

$ret = array();

foreach( $displays as $display){
  array_push($ret, array(
    'title'   => $display['display_title'],
    'path'    => $display['display_options']['path']
  ));
}

return new JsonResponse( $ret );
```